# Time series Count-data forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, count-data

I have sales data shows the number of units sold (so it is a count data). 
I am evaluating the following models:

1. the lightgbm
2. Count Time Series Following Generalised Linear Models (R tscount library)
3. arima (R forecast library)
4. Multiple Aggregation Prediction Algorithm (MAPA  R library)

What would be the advantages and pitfalls of these models?

I would appreciate if you give me a piece of brief information on it.

This is only one of the TS. the data is a collection of 5000 ts.

Comment: They all assume that there are no anomalies in the data. If you post one of your examples it might help the discussion.

Comment: @IrishStat I add a plot of one the time series I have. I do not know what happened why there is such a jump in this particular ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data suggests not on;y a mean shift but a change in variance AND an anomaly at the last point. What you need to do is to identify a SARIMA model https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf and include any and all latent deterministic structure .

Consider http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and any and all posts in SE dealing with INTERVENTION DETECTION https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+INTERVENTION+DETECTION.

In my opinion none of the approaches you mentioned are sophisticated enough or general enough to deal with your kind of data in a comprehensive manner.

If you wish post the data fro your example and I will be of more help. Other readers might also be able to help.

Stay way clear of auto.arima as it assumes no deterministic structure is present i.e. no level/step shifts , no local time trends using deterministic structure , no pulses AND assumes that all error variance treatments can be dealt with using power transforms ( logs et al ). It will inadvertently suggest a differencing operator to deal with the deterministic level shift. It will incorrectly suggest logarithms since the error variance is higher at the higher level [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers) whereas a Weighted Least Squares approach is more correct when the error variance changes at discrete points in time as in this case.